# Is there a clean way to have Bots reply to email threads using the Azure BotFramework?

Tags: botframework, office365, httpresponse, email

I am developing a bot which uses the email channel to communicate and is replying to email threads.

I could not find any documentation about automatic reply formatting or replying to threads at all. It seems like most of the use cases are just one shot emails out to users.

The way the currently implementation is working is that it casts the incoming message to a model (which has all of the relevant info, ToRecipients, Body [html of the email], Text body[plain text of email], ect).
Using that, the header is split from the Body, add the bots reply with a manually created header, and attach the rest of the email to the end of it. The code then either replaces of removes text artifacts from the html response. And then down the line calls SendActivityAsync to send the message.

There are multiple problems with this approach. Some of which include, text artifacts like carriage returns (\r\n) others like (><o:p>&nbsp) which are added to the response automatically through some blackbox formatting function and not removed. Outlook formatting like having emails addresses encased in < and > in the incoming message but not formatting them properly for out going.

Is there any way to make replying to threads easier, or any official support for it? 
If not is there at least any documentation about how emails are parsed in or out that could help make parsing these responses a little easier/clearner?

Answer (score 0):

The Bot Framework has an email channel that can be used like any other channel. The JSON format for the emails is this:

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "locale": "en-Us",
    "channelID": "email",
    "from": { "id": "mybot@mydomain.com", "name": "My bot"},
    "recipient": { "id": "joe@otherdomain.com", "name": "Joe Doe"},
    "conversation": { "id": "123123123123", "topic": "awesome chat" },
    "channelData":
    {
        "htmlBody": "<html><body style = /"font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;/" >This is more than awesome.</body></html>",
        "subject": "Super awesome message subject",
        "importance": "high",
        "ccRecipients": "Yasemin@adatum.com;Temel@adventure-works.com"
    }
}
```

This is changed in the channelData, accessed  through `turnContext.Activity.ChannelData`

The official doc for this is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), and an example implementation of how to work with channelData (though it's Facebook channel, not email) is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/61.facebook-adapter).